SSIS packages deployed not appearing anywhere in SQL Server
We are unable to see our SSIS packages in SQL Server. When we deploy the package to the server, the project shows the latest deployment version but the project doesn't include the deployed package. We tried several times redeploying the project and still no luck resolving this issue. We even tried to contact Microsoft and even they could not figure out. I tried all the options I could find on internet to troubleshoot this with no success.
SQL Server Version is 2019
Any insights on this would be appreciated.
We tried the below steps

Restarted Integration Services
Used different versions of Visual Studio
Created new project and redeployed new packages
Verified permissions on SSISDB

We are expecting to see our SSIS package under project it is deployed.

How did you deploy?

We tried deploying Visual Studio, the deployment wizard and command line. The deployment is successful but the package is not there in server

Can you provide a sample of the command line deploy? I think that would help me understand what your environment looks like

I hope you are doing SSIS Project level deployments. Not individual packages.
For deployment make your AD account a member of SSIS ssis_admin role.

Visual Studio SSIS Project has a Description property. By
default it is empty. It is a good idea to put there what a
particular build and deployment is about. It will show up on the
server side, and reveal what was deployed and when.
Individual SSIS packages also have a Description property. That property is visible on a SSIS Catalog. So, it is possible to compare Visual Studio vs. SSIS server.
SSIS Catalog by default keeps 10 latest versions (it is a configurable number), i.e. deployed projects. And allows to switch between them on the fly. It simulates a rollback in cases of bugs, etc.
When SSIS Project is deployed, it deployed in its entirety as
.ispac file. So, it couldn't be a missing package.
You can always check all SSIS Project builds, their versions (LSN), deployment date, and Descriptions mentioned above. Right mouse click on the project name, and select Versions... option. Please see below.



We don't do  project level deployments. We do package level deployment only because we don't want to deploy packages that dont work.

What is your (1) VS version, (2) SQL Server Integration Services Projects VS extension version, and (3) SSIS run-time version on a server?
